# Making a Jersey bean validation annotation generic

Tags: java, rest, validation, jersey

I have a Jersey Rest API like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/doorder")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces("text/plain")
public String doOrder(@BeanParam final @Valid OrderBean order) {

    // Some implementation here
}
```

All my inputs are store in this bean:

```
@AddressAtLeastOne
public final class OrderBean {

    @FormDataParam("address")
    private String address;

    @FormDataParam("city")
    private String city;

    @FormDataParam("postcode")
    private String postcode;

        // Other member variables

        // Getters and setters

}
```

I added an annotation to validate the address (@AddressAtLeastOne). The address is valid if at least one of the 3 fields has a value.

Here's the annotation definition:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = AddressAtLeastOneValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface AddressAtLeastOne {

    String message() default "Address requires at least one field";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And here's the validator:

```
public class AddressAtLeastOneValidator implements ConstraintValidator<AddressAllOrNone, OrderBean> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(OrderBean demoBean, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    // Check for at least one value
    if((demoBean.getAddress() != null && !demoBean.getAddress().equals("") ||
            (demoBean.getCity() != null && !demoBean.getCity().equals("")) ||
            (demoBean.getPostcode() != null && !demoBean.getPostcode().equals("")))) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

Everything is fine! But now I want to rename the annotation @AddressAtLeastOne to @AtLeastOne and make it generic, so that I can apply it to any class. I need a mechanism where I can specify which member variables are part of the group I want to validate with @AtLeastOne. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach of doing this is to use `Reflection` -

1. Create a custom `annotation` suppose `@GroupNotNullField` and apply this `annotation` to all fields in `bean class` in which at least one field should have value. By this way, you can skip some fields in which validation is not required.
2. In the `validator class`, get all the fields of the `bean class` using `Reflection`
3. Check all the fields which are annotated with `@GroupNotNullField annotation`
4. Get the value of all such fields and check that at least one has value.
5. Return `true` or `false` depending on validation check.

Comment: I created the annotation @AtLeastOne(group="address") at class-level and the annotation @Group(name="address") at field level. It works fine